# Centering adjacent images with flexbox

Tags: css, image, svg, flexbox

I'm trying to use flexbox to display a variable number of image icons centered horizontally in a container.

1. A single icon should be scaled to the container height and centered horizontally.
2. A small number of icons should be scaled to the container height and drawn directly adjacent and centered.
3. If there are more icons than can fit horizontally at the container height, they should be scaled so they do fit without changing their aspect ratio.

I have succeeded with (1) and (3), but (2) is giving me trouble. The images are not drawn adjacent to each other. Here's what it looks like:

[image: scaled/centered icon group test]

Here's the HTML document that produces that output ([also jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/er2k5xdv/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 2in;
  height: 0.5in;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 1 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.block-container {
  width: 2in;
  height: 0.5in;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
<body>
  One item displays centered at container height.
  <div class="flex-container">
    <svg class="flex-item" width="1.0055in" height="1.0055in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 72.395996 72.395999" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(72.198 -89.402)">
        <circle cx="-36" cy="125.6" r="36" fill="#fc0000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".396"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>

  Many items get scaled to fit in the box, which is
  what I want. The image aspect ratio correctly remains
  unchanged.
  <div class="flex-container">
    <svg class="flex-item" width="1.0055in" height="1.0055in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 72.395996 72.395999" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(72.198 -89.402)">
        <circle cx="-36" cy="125.6" r="36" fill="#fc0000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".396"/>
      </g>
    </svg> 
    <svg class="flex-item" width="1.0055in" height="1.0055in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 72.395996 72.395999" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(72.198 -89.402)">
        <circle cx="-36" cy="125.6" r="36" fill="#fc0000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".396"/>
      </g>
    </svg> 
    <svg class="flex-item" width="1.0055in" height="1.0055in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 72.395996 72.395999" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(72.198 -89.402)">
        <circle cx="-36" cy="125.6" r="36" fill="#fc0000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".396"/>
      </g>
    </svg> 
    <svg class="flex-item" width="1.0055in" height="1.0055in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 72.395996 72.395999" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(72.198 -89.402)">
        <circle cx="-36" cy="125.6" r="36" fill="#fc0000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".396"/>
      </g>
    </svg> 
    <svg class="flex-item" width="1.0055in" height="1.0055in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 72.395996 72.395999" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(72.198 -89.402)">
        <circle cx="-36" cy="125.6" r="36" fill="#fc0000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".396"/>
      </g>
    </svg> 
  </div>

  But if there are not enough images to fill the container
  then I want the images adjacent and centered. Instead
  they are distributed.
  <div class="flex-container">
    <svg class="flex-item" width="1.0055in" height="1.0055in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 72.395996 72.395999" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(72.198 -89.402)">
        <circle cx="-36" cy="125.6" r="36" fill="#fc0000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".396"/>
      </g>
    </svg> 
    <svg class="flex-item" width="1.0055in" height="1.0055in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 72.395996 72.395999" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(72.198 -89.402)">
        <circle cx="-36" cy="125.6" r="36" fill="#fc0000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".396"/>
      </g>
    </svg> 
  </div>

  This is what the above case should look like, but it
  doesn't use flexbox so it won't scale properly with
  many items.
  <div class="block-container">
    <svg class="flex-item" width="1.0055in" height="1.0055in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 72.395996 72.395999" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(72.198 -89.402)">
        <circle cx="-36" cy="125.6" r="36" fill="#fc0000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".396"/>
      </g>
    </svg><svg class="flex-item" width="1.0055in" height="1.0055in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 72.395996 72.395999" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(72.198 -89.402)">
        <circle cx="-36" cy="125.6" r="36" fill="#fc0000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".396"/>
      </g>
    </svg> 
  </div>
</body>
```

I really thought that `justify-content: center` was exactly for this situation, but I can't get that to work. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Can someone point it out?

Comment: Your HTML code is invalid -- there is no `<html>` element, and `<style>` should be within `<head>` element.

Comment: @Manjuboyz Yes, I wanted the third and fourth images to look the same, but with flexbox. Your answer works fine, just a little later and without the explanation that the accepted answer had.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually , you have just to delete the `flex:1 1;` cause it is making the images takes the availabe space.

jsfiddle exemple : https://jsfiddle.net/gzxu5va8/2/

**CSS :**

```
.flex-container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:center;
  width: 2in;
  height: 0.5in;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.flex-item {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:center;
}

.block-container {
  width: 2in;
  height: 0.5in;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess this what you looking for:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 2in;
  height: 0.5in;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.center {
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.block-container {
  width: 2in;
  height: 0.5in;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  One item displays centered at container height.
  <div class="flex-container center">
    <svg class="flex-item" width="1.0055in" height="1.0055in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 72.395996 72.395999" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(72.198 -89.402)">
        <circle cx="-36" cy="125.6" r="36" fill="#fc0000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".396"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>

  Many items get scaled to fit in the box, which is what I want. The image aspect ratio correctly remains unchanged.
  <div class="flex-container">
    <svg class="flex-item" width="1.0055in" height="1.0055in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 72.395996 72.395999" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(72.198 -89.402)">
        <circle cx="-36" cy="125.6" r="36" fill="#fc0000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".396"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <svg class="flex-item" width="1.0055in" height="1.0055in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 72.395996 72.395999" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(72.198 -89.402)">
        <circle cx="-36" cy="125.6" r="36" fill="#fc0000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".396"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <svg class="flex-item" width="1.0055in" height="1.0055in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 72.395996 72.395999" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(72.198 -89.402)">
        <circle cx="-36" cy="125.6" r="36" fill="#fc0000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".396"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <svg class="flex-item" width="1.0055in" height="1.0055in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 72.395996 72.395999" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(72.198 -89.402)">
        <circle cx="-36" cy="125.6" r="36" fill="#fc0000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".396"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <svg class="flex-item" width="1.0055in" height="1.0055in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 72.395996 72.395999" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(72.198 -89.402)">
        <circle cx="-36" cy="125.6" r="36" fill="#fc0000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".396"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>

  But if there are not enough images to fill the container then I want the images adjacent and centered. Instead they are distributed.
  <div class="flex-container center">
    <svg class="flex-item" width="1.0055in" height="1.0055in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 72.395996 72.395999" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(72.198 -89.402)">
        <circle cx="-36" cy="125.6" r="36" fill="#fc0000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".396"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <svg class="flex-item" width="1.0055in" height="1.0055in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 72.395996 72.395999" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(72.198 -89.402)">
        <circle cx="-36" cy="125.6" r="36" fill="#fc0000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".396"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>

  This is what the above case should look like, but it doesn't use flexbox so it won't scale properly with many items.
  <div class="block-container">
    <svg class="flex-item" width="1.0055in" height="1.0055in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 72.395996 72.395999" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(72.198 -89.402)">
        <circle cx="-36" cy="125.6" r="36" fill="#fc0000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".396"/>
      </g>
    </svg><svg class="flex-item" width="1.0055in" height="1.0055in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 72.395996 72.395999" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(72.198 -89.402)">
        <circle cx="-36" cy="125.6" r="36" fill="#fc0000" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width=".396"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>
```